# [How To Question] Specific scrape sound

Tags: sfx, sound-design, metal, sound-effects

Hey there,

I'm trying to reproduce this spesific SFX, but i couldn't figure out how to create that scrape. Regular sword (fish slice) scrapes just won't work. Any ideas?

the sound: http://snd.sc/PbYGrV

Answer (score 1):

Hi,

It's a combination of several sound events:
A pitched up scrape of metal (on a sharpening stone?)
Typical horror slush sound (from tomatoes?)
A shortened whoosh sound (cloth?)

Good luck

Arnoud

Comment: thanks for insight! i'm done with swoosh foley and the squish. i'm stuck at the scrape part. no matter what i do, can't get the dynamics of that one, and that's what i'm asking about :<

Comment: sorry i didn't get that from the question. but did you try the metal on stone i mentioned? or combine it with Erik's trick?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use two knives with a quick stroke together? Works everytime for me. + some epic pitchshifter on that. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've found this works very well with a large chef's knife. If you slide one blade along the other you get a really nice resonating ring to it. For a slightly dirtier version, use one blade along a knife sharper.

Answer (score 0):

On top of the other suggestions so far, try the knife on many surfaces. If it's not a knife you care about, use brick, stone, soil, gravel, various woods, vegetables, etc. to cut into/scrape against. Come to think of it, I wouldn't suggest using one of my good knives for this anyway ;).

Do you have a sampler plugin or something you can use to map out sounds to a midi keyboard? It takes a little more setup time, but this is one of my favorite ways to quickly audition different combinations of sounds. Grab your favorite cut/scrape samples and assign each to an octave of the keyboard (C to C). Put the default pitch at F#. This lets you freely play with layering of sounds AND pitch shifting up to 6 semitones simultaneously.

Have fun! 
~Matt